# Javascript / Logic issue while using querying and a couple conditionals.

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

So I am using adonis to build a very basic back-end for an image hosting site such as reddit or imgur. I am having an issue with one of my controllers while trying to give users the ability to vote on posts, but limiting each user to vote only once per post.

this is my controller class file:

---

```
'use strict'

const Vote = use('App/Model/Vote')
const Post = use('App/Model/Post')


class VoteController {
  * create (request, response) {
let currentUser = request.authUser
let postId = request.param('post_id')
let data = {}
data.user_id = currentUser.id
data.post_id = postId

let voteCheck = yield Vote.query()
  .where({'post_id': postId,
          'user_id': currentUser.id })
console.log(voteCheck)

if (voteCheck) {
  response.status(401).json({error: "User can only cast 1 vote per post."})
} else {
  let addVote = yield Vote.create(data)
  yield addVote.save();
  let post = yield Post.findBy('id', data.post_id)
  let votes = post.vote_count;
  if (votes === null ) {
    votes = 1;
  } else {
    votes++;
  }
  post.vote_count = votes;
  yield post.save()

  response.status(202).json([post, addVote]);
  }
 }

}
```

> module.exports = VoteController

---

I have been playing around with different combinations of conditionals. My main issue is with the variable 'voteCheck'. Essentially if a user votes, it creates a new column in my 'votes' table that stores the authUser's id and the post's id. I have a query before my conditional that searches for a pre-existing vote matching that criteria, and if it exists, throws an error. If not (else) it creates a new vote and adds 1 to the posts 'vote_count'. The latter is working just fine but I believe there is something wrong with my conditional logic as I am currently getting an error even for users who have not yet voted. Any suggestions? Thanks a bunch for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to execute the query chain. Put `.fetch()` at the end of your query.

```
let voteCheck = yield Vote.query()
  .where({'post_id': postId,
          'user_id': currentUser.id })
  .fetch()
```